# Autofac: Resolve Lists with only one element fails

Tags: c#, autofac

**1. Case:**

Registrations:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ExportSchedule>()
       .As<ISchedule>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<ImportReferenceDataSchedule>()
       .As<ISchedule>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Resolving for **BaseconfigScheduleHandler** class:

```
public BaseConfigScheduleHandler(List<ISchedule> schedules) {
    this.Schedules = schedules;
}

public List<ISchedule> Schedules { get; }
```

This case works fine. I got both registered instances of **ISchedule**.

**2. Case**

I change the registrations to only register 1 element:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ExportSchedule>()
       .As<ISchedule>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In this case the dependency resolution fails with following exception:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An error occurred during
>   the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception
>   for details. Registration: Activator = BaseConfigScheduleHandler
>   (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [docXtrans.TuevApi.Core.Data.Service.IScheduleHandler], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared,
>   Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found
>   with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on
>   type 'docXtrans.TuevApi.Core.Data.Service.BaseConfigScheduleHandler'
>   can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot
>   resolve parameter
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ISchedule]
>   schedules' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BaseConfigSchedule],
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ISchedule])'.
>   (See inner exception for details.)

I need both cases and want to be flexible having 1 or more elements in this collection. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using one of the supported enumeration types. As per [the docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b):

> Enumeration (IEnumerable, IList, ICollection)

In your case, that could be:

```
IEnumerable<ISchedule> schedules
```